# Batch Image files - Replace spaces with an underscore in filename

Tags: image, filenames, batch-processing

I want to go through a folder and replace all the spaces in a filename with an underscore. For example the image "dark green.jpg" would change to "dark_green.jpg". I have hundreds of images that a client uploaded to a site that need to be changed so I would like a way to batch it.

Is there an quick and easy way to do this? It can be in photoshop, bridge or just using some native windows function.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php

Answer (score 6):

Using Windows PowerShell the following should work:

```
ls *.jpg | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace " ","_" }
```